# Magical Records import JSON to Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, magicalrecord

Say I have core data entities below:

Event.h

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * event_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * event_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * event_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * event_status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *event_persons;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Store *store;

@end
```

Store.h

```
@interface Store : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * store_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * store_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * store_type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *events;
@end
```

Event_person.h

```
@interface Event_person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *event_person_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Event *event;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person_type *person_type;

@end
```

Person_type.h

```
@interface person_type : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *person_type_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Event_person *event_person;

@end
```

If I receive a JSON from the API like this:

```
{
    "event_id": "12345",
    "event_name": "Demo",
    "event_date": "March 24 2015 12:00AM",
    "store": {
        "store_id": "789",
        "store_name": "Costco",
        "store_type": "Warehouse"
    },
    "event_person": [
        {
            "event_id": "580814",
            "name": "John",
            "person_type": {
                "person_type_id": "abc123",
                "type": "Demonstrator"
            }
        },
        {
            "event_id": "580814",
            "name": "Jane",
            "person_type": {
                "person_type_id": "cdf345",
                "type": "Helper"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In my completion block I have `NSDictionary *resultDict = /// result from JSON parser` then import the return value to my `Event NSManagedObject`

```
Event *imported Event = [Person MR_importFromObject:resultDict];
```

Questions:

1) Say no Event, Store, Event_person or Person_type objects exist based on the id returned, will magical records create all the objects in the hierachy of the return JSON and also fill in properties like

`NSSet *event_persons and Store *store` for `Event` object

`NSSet *events` for `Store` object

`NSSet *events` and `Person_type *person_type` for `Event_person` object

and `Event_person *event_person` for `Person_type` object?

2) Say if some objects already exist, will magical records just update the properties of the object and NOT create a new object?

Thanks,